# set start index for static tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview

I have a static tableviewcontroller (it had to be done this way), but I want to set it to a certain position (index 40) when it loads. Unfortunately, the code below only works when it is not static. Are there alternative ways to accomplish this?

```
 [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:1]
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
                                  animated:NO];
```

Comment: First, you should always use `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]` with table views (section is probably 0 in your case). Second, where do you call this code from? Try `viewWillAppearAnimated:`.

Comment: Have you checked that `tableView` outlet is actually connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the cells are static and they're sizes will always be the same, you could always just adjust the contentOffset property of the table view directly to set which cells are on screen, ex:

```
CGPoint offsetOfCell40 = CGPointMake(0.0f, 2500.0f);
[tableView setContentOffset:offsetOfCell40 animated:NO];
```

Comment: @user2495313 I can be more helpful if you can be more specific.